# Prevent Escape, Delete and Backspace on event.key function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent my typewriter to append backspace, enter and escape. Because I don't need the functions I just want to get rid of it.

Here is my typing-code with some extra functions. (It gets thicker when typing fast.)

```
let lastTime = 0;
const $output = $("#output");
const $content = $('#content');

$(window).on("keypress", function(event) {
  // Timer for Key Latency
  let currTime = new Date();
  let ms = lastTime ? currTime - lastTime : 0;
  $output.text(ms + "ms");
  lastTime = currTime;
  // Fontweight
  var fontWeight = ms > 900 ? 100 : 900 / ms * 100;
  // Typewriter
  var key = event.key;
  $content.append('<span style="font-weight:' + fontWeight + '">' + key + '</span>');
```

I tried to add the following jQuery-script to the event.key function but nothing happens.

```
if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
        return false;
```

[Codepen/Project/Typewriter](https://codepen.io/danborjesson/pen/byWJbd)

Comment: use `event.which === 8` as far as i know some browsers handle the keycodes diffrently but the jquery event.which retuns you reliably the keycodes no matter what browser you use

Comment: Thanks! But it still types the content: Backspace, enter and escape!

Comment: It doesnt though $(window).on("keypress", function(event) {if(event.which === 13 || event.which === 8 || event.which === 46) {
    console.log('No output');
    return;
  }...`